# Adding Atl support to console project in vs2017

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to VC++, MFC and ATL.
I am trying to add ATL support to a console project which I have created for unit testing using CppUnit.
There are few com interfaces I need to test, for which I need to add an ATL simple obj in my console test project.
Few things that I have tried are to create an idl file and manually created a .rgs file but I am unable to register the same to my registry, due to which the class id is returning null...
Please help me understand how to add an ATL support to my console project

Thanks in advance...